# Output File with Sink(): Stop Sink() outputting commands

Tags: r, sink

I should say that I am rather new to R.

I am attempting to use the sink() function to write output to a new file.

Sink() appears to be returning everything, including all commands, when I just want it to show output.

For example:

If I run the following code from source:

```
sink("hello.txt")
cat("hello world")
sink()
```

RStudio creates a new file with the following text inside:

```
> cat("hello world")
hello world
> sink()
```

I thought this should just output

```
hello world
```

Can someone please tell me how to make sink() ignore commands?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: That seems to work for me, what version of R are you using and are you using RStudio?

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for getting back so quickly. I am using RStudio, version 1.1.447.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the following code from source" ? Are you using the `source()` function?

Comment: Hi guys, just to let you know. It had something to do with Echo being set to TRUE. I have no idea how this happened, but turning it into FALSE sorted everything out. Hopefully, this helps others in future. Thank you for your comments. Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Run` instead of `Source`, you will have the output only in the `.txt` file. I am not sure why it that.